# Route model binding and parent child validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, model-binding

Say I have a route like:

`Route::get('users/{user}/posts/{post}', 'PostController@show')`

And I've set up Route Model binding for an `App\User` to `{user}` and an `App\Post` to `{post}`. I've seen I'm able to call whatever existing post for any given user to get contents on the screen. Is there a generic place where I can assign constraints to the bound models?

Comment: how about in the controller?

Comment: I know it can be done there, but I'm wondering if Taylor created a little hidden gem for stuff like this somewhere else.

Comment: If your are using Laravel 5+, there is a file: `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`. place in the `map` method. And as @noodles_ftw suggested, but change the `first`, to `firstOrFail`. I'm beleiving, if you place the user bind first, it will shown an error is no such user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$router->bind()` to control how a model is fetched:

`Route::get('/user/{name}', 'PostController@show');`

```
$router->bind('user', function($value) {
    return App\User::where('name', $value)->first();
});
```

Comment: I never thought of implementing it in a function, I always just put the name of the model there. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

you can use `Route::bind` and set a second variable for the function to access the current route and it parameters like this:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        $router->bind('user', function($value) {
            return App\User::findOrFail($value);
        });

        $router->bind('post', function($value, $route) {
            return $route->parameter('user')->posts()->findOrFail($value);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This certainly is a gap in laravel.  I made a little package to help.
https://github.com/tarekadam/laravel-orm-binding-validation

1. Use middleware not validation.
2. Append the middleware so that binding already ran.
3. Define the expected relationships in the controller.

See README.md on the package.